# What's the proper way to test SPA angular application which relies heavily websockets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, websocket, protractor

I'm using protractor with jasmine to test our angular 1.5 based application. The page also uses reactjs to handle streams which sources are websockets. Protractor is only responsible for angular based events/states. The problem is, sometimes I have to wait for data to arrive from the Websockets. Right now we are doing it by manual waits, but that's unstable and lame. I'm guessing somehow I have to listen to that websocket manually, but I'm not sure. 
**What would be the best way to wait for data coming from Websockets?**